# push on git a folder containing folders, which contains folders, which contains folders and files within folders

Tags: git

I would like to push on git a folder containing folders, which contains folders, which contains folders and files within folders...

I've tried different kinds of methods like:
`git add -A --force`

But only the folders within the first folder are pushed, but not their content. And the whole structure of folders and files are not pushed. How to push a folder with its complete structure of folders and files, which can have many sub levels ?

Can someone please tell me the appropriate command lines on git and if it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Are there nested repositories (`.git/` directories) deep inside the hierarchy? You cannot add nested repositories.Either make them [tag:git-submodules] or rename/remove `.git/` directories to add deep folders.

Comment: Thanks. Yes there are nested repositories. I've tried git-sumodules. And I can see the folder structure on GitHub. The problem is that when I download the project, there is nothing within the folder. Please see the link: https://github.com/Xon77/Live4Life/tree/main/L4L_Quarks

Comment: And if I rename/remove .git/ directories to add deep folders, I've got issues to push my project, because my references are lost...

Comment: "*I can see the folder structure on GitHub. The problem is that when I download the project, there is nothing within the folder.*" You've forgotten to add, commit and push the file `.gitmodules`. "*if I rename/remove .git/ directories to add deep folders, I've got issues*" Well, now when they're submodules you shouldn't rename deep `.git` . It was an advice in the directory before and instead submodules.

Comment: In my project, there is the folder with the content, the problem is that if someone wants to download the code in zip, by clicking on code on the webpage, the content is not there. I don't know if I am clear...

Comment: I've added, committed and pushed the file .gitmodules. But, I still have have the problem if someone wants to download the project simply with zip. Is there a way to get also all the content of the submodules in the zip folder?

Comment: With zip — no. `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/Xon77/Live4Life`

Comment: Thanks, since I needed a way that some users could download the submodules without installing Git, I created a zip file within the folder which contains also all the submodules via both commands : `git archive -o release.zip HEAD` and `git submodule --quiet foreach 'cd $toplevel; zip -ru release.zip $sm_path'`. But, is there a way to get only the submodules in the zip file, and not the whole structure folder, which is redundant ?

Comment: you can see it [there](https://github.com/Xon77/Live4Life)